# mysql merge records until a value is changed

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database table similar to below.

[image]

And i want a result set which provides the start time and end time when the type value changes, similar to below. The type values are dynamic and not just 1,2... and also the rows also will not be continuous.

[image]

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: We are using mysql 5.6

Comment: Can timeranges overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT MIN(start_time) start_time,
       MAX(end_time) end_time,
       MAX(type) type
FROM ( SELECT start_time, end_time,
              CASE WHEN type = @type
                   THEN @grp
                   ELSE @grp:=@grp + 1
                   END grp,
              @type:=type type
       FROM test
       CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @type:=0, @grp:=0) init_var
       ORDER BY start_time ) divided
GROUP BY grp
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=7490dd2d75cc0fe3388e6ad00df4ee51

The query assumes that the timeranges does not overlap.